# How do I display Arabic text?

Tags: html

I have researched this and all similar questions do not provide an answer. I am using utf-8 on my page. The page, BTW, is http://www.publishmymusic.com/profile/artist/1361.

If I use phpMyAdmin, I see Arabic characters in the database. But when I read and display them, they look like what you see at the above URL. I have looked and looked and cannot find a solution to this problem so it must be subtle. The database is utf8_general_ci. The column itself is utf8_general_ci. The page hast the correct meta tag got utf-8 charset. But it must be possible because phpMyAdmin shows the characters in Arabic. Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: `utf8_general_ci` is **not** an encoding, it's a collation. Execute `SET NAMES utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;` right after establishing the connection.

Comment: Try using `mysqli::set_charset` or `mysql_set_charset` to set the connection character set to `utf8`. I believe it might default to `latin1`. I'm assuming you're using PHP, although you didn't specify..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You display Arabic HTML by including Arabic UTF-8 text in your HTML. In some cases, you also need to add [dir attributes](http://www.i18nguy.com/markup/right-to-left.html) to improve the presentation.

Apparently, you have some code, which you haven't told us about, that reads your database and produces HTML. That code has to avoid corrupting the text.

Comment: I am just retrieving the titles column from the database and displaying it. Yes, I am using PHP and codeigniter.

Answer (score 1):

set `default table collate` to `utf8_general_ci` and also set `default table charset` to `utf8`, It should work

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_name (column_list)
    [[DEFAULT] CHARACTER SET utf8]
    [COLLATE utf8_general_ci]]
```